# how to dynamically insert character in middle input text with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keypress

I have an input text box to fill in with hours from 00:00 to 23:59
I'd like to dynamically insert the double point ":" after the 2 first characters, something like in http://www.railtime.be/website/home-fr which is even giving an error message when wrong hours are given like 30:66... I can't figure out how it has been done, any idea?

```
<input type="text" name="time" id="time" placeholder="00:00" maxlength="5" value="">
```

I think a keypress function has been used but what with?
Thanks in advance!

**Resolved with dfsq solution:**

```
$('input#time').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which && this.value.length === 2 && e.which !== 8) {
        this.value += ':';
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not use the `<input type="time">`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6rajxg5a/ You will also handle paste event.

Comment: Thanks for your help dfsq! :)
j08691: I'm not using type = time for compatibility reason, it's not working on IE and FF unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="time">` isn't supported in Firefox etc.
If you wish to avoid jQuery, just use this simple code wherein your ':' would be inserted at the time of typing itself using the keyup event-

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function insertColon(e){
    var unicode=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode
    if(unicode!=8){// this avoids backspace to spoil your logic
        var textval=document.getElementById("time").value;  
        if(textval.length==3&&textval.charAt(1)!=":"&&textval.charAt(2)!=":"){// this case arises when backspace is used
            textval=textval.substring(0,2)+":"+textval.substring(2,3);
            document.getElementById("time").value=textval;
        }
        else if(textval.length==2&&textval.charAt(1)!=":"){// normal case
            textval=textval+":";
            document.getElementById("time").value=textval;
        }
    }
    else if(unicode==46&&textval.length>=3&&textval.charAt(1)!=":"&&textval.charAt(2)!=":"){
    textval=textval.substring(0,2)+":"+textval.substring(2);`document.getElementById("time").value=textval;`
}

}  
</script>
</head>
<body>    
<input type="text" name="time" id="time" placeholder="00:00" maxlength="5" value="" onKeyup="insertColon(event);">    
</body>
</html>
```

You can yourself add some little code to script to check if the ranges of hours and minutes are falling within range.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you out. http://jsfiddle.net/e2DzT/380/

It checks for the correct format, and if it is empty. It will output the correct response. Format can be only in 15:30 format.

When the correct format is found, the form is submitted.

```
<form id="login" name="login" method="post" action="#">
```

Just change it to what you want it to do.

Comment: It probably should also give a validation warning on the value 8:8. Lose the ? in the minutes part.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following Javascript code:

```js
function appendColon(){
    var time=document.getElementById("time").value;
    var hours=time.substring(0, 2);
    var minutes=time.substring(2, 4);
    document.getElementById("time").value=hours+":"+minutes;  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="time" id="time" onchange="appendColon()" placeholder="00:00" maxlength="5" value="">
```

In the onchange event of the input, appends `:` between hours and minutes.